# Most simple expression of $ \prod_{k=1}^{n}k^k$

Tags: calculus, products

I'm looking for the most simple form, perhaps without product symbol, of $\displaystyle  \prod_{k=1}^{n}k^k$ for any positive number $n$. Maybe this is already the most simple form?

What I've done so far is:

$$\displaystyle  \prod_{k=1}^{n}k^k =\prod_{k=1}^{n}e^{k \ln (k)} = e^{\sum_{k=1}^n k\ln(k)}$$

And from there I've search online, for instance [[here]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series), an easier expression of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k \ln(k)$ but couldn't manage to find one.

We know that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n  \ln(k) = \ln(n!)~$ but we here need $k\ln(k)$.

So my guess is either I didn't search well, either there is no more simple expression of $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k \ln(k)$ depending of $n$ and without $\sum$ for instance, or the solution isn't going trough exponential form. Could you help me find out?

Comment: One can see this is equivalent to $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{k!}$$

Comment: [OEIS A002109](https://oeis.org/A002109) yields no simpler formula but reveals that these are called *hyperfactorials*.

Comment: It is the hyperfactorial. There is no simpler form. You may find some properties here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I didn't know it already has a name and thus was studied :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
$$ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{k!} = \frac{n!^n}{G(n+1)} $$
where $G(n)$ is the Barnes' G function, it is easy to extend the
original definition to non-integer $n.$  Furthermore, the asymptotics
of both the $\Gamma$ and $G$ functions are known, so the OP's 
expression has an easily derived asymptotic formula.  For even 
moderate $n,$ say,$ n>6,$ this is more than likely preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gary, @RobPratt and @Tavish's comments these are called *hyperfactorials*.

I could find info [here-OEIS A002109](https://oeis.org/A002109) and [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html).

Another form is:

$$ \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \dfrac{n!}{k!}$$